# How do we prove that $(x^2 + y^2)^2 + x^2 + y^2 < 1$ is a disk?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

How do I see that $(x^2 + y^2)^2 + x^2 + y^2 < 1$ is a disk? I plotted it in wolfram alpha and it looks like a disk, but I don't know how to show it algebraically.

Even if we write in polar coordinates,
$r^4 + r^2 < 1$, I don't know why this is a disk.

Isn't a disk $r^2 < 1$?

Comment: Not a sphere. A sphere is a quadratic surface.

Comment: I meant a circle

Comment: A disk of radius $1$ centered at the origin is $r^2 < 1$. If you don't have to prove what the radius is, all you really need to know is that there's some value of $r$ that makes $r^4+r^2=1$ and every smaller non-negative value of $r$ makes $r^4+r^2<1$.

Answer (score 2):

If you let $x = r\cos(\theta)$ and $y = r\sin(\theta)$ where $r\geq 0$ and $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$, then it results that:

\begin{align*}
(x^{2} + y^{2})^{2} + x^{2} + y^{2} < 1 & \Longleftrightarrow r^{4} + r^{2} < 1\\
& \Longleftrightarrow r^{4} + r^{2} + \frac{1}{4} < \frac{5}{4}\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \left(r^{2} + \frac{1}{2}\right)^{2} < \frac{5}{4}\\
& \Longleftrightarrow r^{2} + \frac{1}{2} < \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\\
& \Longleftrightarrow r^{2} < \frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{2}\\
& \Longleftrightarrow r < \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{2}}
\end{align*}
which is an open disk, as it can be seen in the following picture (created by mathematica):

[image]

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Let $D = x^2 + y^2$ (so that $d = \sqrt{D}$ is the length of the vector $(x, y)$). Then the constraint is that:

$$
D^2 + D < 1
$$

But as $D$ is non-negative, $D^2+D$ is a monotone increasing function of $D$, so the constraint is equivalent to a positive upper bound on $D$ and hence on the length $d$ of the vector $(x, y)$. The set of vectors of length less than some positive upper bound is a disk.

Answer (score 1):

Write it as $(x^2 + y^2 + 1/4)^2 < 5/4$.  Since $x^2 + y^2 + 1/4 > 0$, this is equivalent to $x^2 + y^2 < \sqrt{5/4} - 1/4$.

Comment: Is there a way to easily see it from the polar inequality?

Comment: Are you sure about that? I believe it should be $ (x^2 + y^2 + 1/2) ^2 < 5/4$.